# Unity Open VR application launched from within android application

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, oculus

i am trying to launch a VR Android Application using OVR that was built in Unity3D. I want the Unity Application to be part of the android app, and not two separate applications.
To do this, i exported the compiled application as AAR Library into my application.

The launching of regular Unity3D apps works fine. Using the OVR Plugin causes an error message however, saying:

```
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/Test_Data/Mono/libOVRPlugin
Unity v5.6.1f1, Oculus Utilities v1.12.0, OVRPlugin v0.0.0, SDK v0.0.0.
```

and:

```
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/Test_Data/Mono/libOVRPlugin
DllNotFoundException: OVRPlugin
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) OVRPlugin/OVRP_1_1_0:ovrp_GetNodePresent (OVRPlugin/Node)
  at OVRPlugin.get_hmdPresent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OVRManager.get_isHmdPresent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OVRDisplay.ConfigureEyeDesc (VRNode eye) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OVRDisplay.UpdateTextures () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OVRDisplay..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OVRManager.Awake () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

and later, with the nullreferenceexception repeating while the app is running:

```
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/Test_Data/Mono/.\libOVRPlugin
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/Test_Data/Mono/libOVRPlugin
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at OVRCameraRig.UpdateAnchors () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OVRCameraRig.FixedUpdate () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

[**From what i could find here**](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/190173/dllnotfoundexception-in-standalone.html), there seem to be some path issues? It is not the same problem though, and I do not know how to fix this problem. The unity scene is not acting like it should  because of it (It shows a white screen, skips a scene on launch and other problems)

What can i do to fix this?